# Backbone model validation undefined attrs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I've got my model which I'm trying to validate, according to the books this should work, however I'm receiving attrs as undefined.

```
validate: (attrs, options)->
    attrs
```

if I go ahead and do it this way:

```
validate: ->
    this.attributes
```

I can access the model's attributes just fine however I don't think this is the recommended way to do it.

this is my model code:

```
class Todo extends Backbone.Model
    defaults: 
        title: 'default title'
        completed: false
    validate: (attrs, options)->
        attrs
myTodo new Todo
myTodo.validate()
//returns false because attrs is undefined
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> **validate** `model.validate(attributes, options)`
>
> [...] By default **validate** is called before `save`, but can also be called before `set` if `{validate:true}` is passed.

So `validate` is meant to be called by Backbone, not directly by you. You're calling `validate` yourself:

```
myTodo.validate()
```

but not passing any arguments so `attrs` is `undefined` because, well, you didn't pass its value.

You're supposed to let Backbone call `validate` when you call `myTodo.save()` or `myTodo.set(new_values, validate: true)`.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Now it feels pretty obvious! :)